# name not defined error when using a Pandas DF in Python function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a function using this df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"a": [1,2,3],
        "b": [5,6,7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    a   b
0   1   5
1   2   6
2   3   7
```

The function is this:

```
def function(x):
    y = df.query("a > x")
    return y

y=function(1)
print(y)
```

When I call the function, I get the error that x is not defined?

What is the issue here?

Comment: Try `y = df[df["a"] > x]`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a variable with `df.query`, use `@`.

You are missing `@` in your `function`.

Do this:

```
In [458]: def function(x):
     ...:     y = df.query("a > @x")
     ...:     return y
     ...: 

In [460]: y=function(1)
     ...: print(y)
   a  b
1  2  6
2  3  7
```

Comment: @williamscathy825 Please let me know if the answer worked for you?